# How to construct a network with two inputs in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

Suppose I want to have the general neural network architecture:

```
Input1 --> CNNLayer 
                    \
                     ---> FCLayer ---> Output
                    /
Input2 --> FCLayer
```

Input1 is image data, input2 is non-image data. I have implemented this architecture in Tensorflow.

All pytorch examples I have found are one input go through each layer. How can I define forward func to process 2 inputs separately then combine them in a middle layer?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By "combine them" I assume you mean to [concatenate](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=norm#torch.cat) the two inputs.
Assuming you concat along the second dimension:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class TwoInputsNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(TwoInputsNet, self).__init__()
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d( ... )  # set up your layer here
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear( ... )  # set up first FC layer
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear( ... )  # set up the other FC layer

  def forward(self, input1, input2):
    c = self.conv(input1)
    f = self.fc1(input2)
    # now we can reshape `c` and `f` to 2D and concat them
    combined = torch.cat((c.view(c.size(0), -1),
                          f.view(f.size(0), -1)), dim=1)
    out = self.fc2(combined)
    return out
```

Note that when you define the number of inputs to `self.fc2` you need to take into account both `out_channels` of `self.conv` as well as the output spatial dimensions of `c`.

Comment: How do I do concatenation if both my inputs are image data? Say 2 grayscale images of dim 120X90?

Comment: @iCHAIT you can concat on the "channel" dimension, provided their spatial size is the same

Comment: Is there some good strategy for normalizing input1 and input2 together? Is that something that should be considered?