# How to run network with multiple independent inputs in parallel in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, neural-network, pytorch

I have a neural network with two separate vectors as inputs, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51700729/how-to-construct-a-network-with-two-inputs-in-pytorch).
Both inputs are encoded and then processed further. But until then, the encoding of those inputs is completely independent.
How can I parallelize the encoding phase in pytorch?
A minimal example of my code:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(params):
        super(MyModel self).__init__()

        self.encoder1 = Encoder1()
        self.encoder2 = Encoder2()

    def forward(x1, x2):
        # how to calculate both encodings in parallel?
        enc1 = self.encoder1(x1)
        enc2 = self.encoder2(x2)
        return some_func(enc1, enc2)
```

I checked pytorch forums and learned a bit about DataParallel, but i am not sure how to fit it to my case and on only 1 GPU.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Usually GPU kernels already use the whole GPU (given a sufficient batch size), so running two computations at once wouldn't increase performance.

Comment: Then how to do it for 2 gpus anyways? The two encoders are independent and can in theory be calculated in parallel