# How can I use 2 images as a training sample in PyTorch？

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, image-classification

I just begin learning deep learning and my first homework is to finish an leaves-classification system based on convolutional neural networks.I built a resnet-34 model with the code on github to do it.However,my teacher told me that the basic training unit in his dataset is an image pair.I should use 2 images(photos of the same leaf under different light conditions) as the input,combining two 3-channel images into one 6-channel image,but I don't know how to input 2 images and combine them into 6 channels.How can I do that?Are there any functions?Should I modify the structure of the resnet network?
[image]
this is my dataset,you can see every two images are about the same leaf.

Comment: You can just concatenate the two images on the last axis. Most images are in the format of (w, h, channels) when converted to a numpy array so you can just concatenate the two arrays on the channels' axis. Or, you can add two input layers on your model and pass them to a Concatenate layer to combine their last axis, works either way.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues to tackle:

1. You need a [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataset#torch.utils.data.Dataset) with a `__getitem__` method that returns 2 images (and a label) instead of the basic ones that returns a single image and a label. You'll probably need to [customize your own dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247893/1714410).
2. Make sure the augmentations you apply to your images are applied in the same manner to each pair.
3. You need to modify ResNet-34 network to get as an input 2 images, instead of one. See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700934/1714410) how that can be done.
4. You need to change the first convolution layer to have 6 input channels instead of 3.
5. If you want to use pre-trained weights you will not be able to load the existing `state_dict` of ResNet34 because of changes #3 and #4 - you'll have to do it manually for the first time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer~ Can you tell me something more about #5? Can I load the existing resnet-34 pre-trained pth files on the github?Or I should train the network totally by myself,without any pre-trained parameters and weights? Looking forward to your reply~

Comment: Thank you again for the answer.I solved my problem with your solution.By the way,I want to know what I should do if I want to get the same effect with VGG-16 model?

Comment: @CodingRookie you will need to adapt `VGG` in the same manner you adapted `ResNet`.